# Simplest way to join Object key value pair with =

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is their any easiest way to solve this

**Join Object with key=value pair**;

```
let a = {a: 'apple', b:'ball', c:'cat'}
```

**expected result**

```
a=apple,b=ball,c=cat
```

**My solution code**

```js
let a = {a: 'apple', b:'ball', c:'cat'}
a = Object.keys(a).map(b => `${b}=${a[b]}`).join(',');
console.log(a)
```

Can I do this with **less code**.

Comment: That is probably the least amount of code to do this.

Comment: drop `','` - it's the default value for `join`.

Comment: You might want to account for whether you care about key ordering in the result string.  Answers here so far presume that you don't care about it.

Comment: Also, by less code, do you mean more concise, or something that's less consumptive of computing resources?

Comment: @danh I assume OP wants to golf it.

Comment: @VLAZ, I had to google "golf in computing" to understand your reply, and discovered incidentally that there's an SE site where maybe this ought to be moved....https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: @danh I'm not sure if it is on-topic there. They tend to do actual golfing challenges, not sure if they help with golfing optimisation.

Comment: instead of join(',') you can use toString()

Comment: @KrystianSztadhaus which is longer than join(",")

Comment: @KrystianSztadhaus which is 1 character more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a=""+Object.entries(a).map(x=>x.join('='));
```

or

```
a=""+Object.keys(a).map(b=>`${b}=${a[b]}`);
```

or

```
a=`${Object.keys(a).map(b=>`${b}=${a[b]}`)}`;
```

are shorter than

```
a=Object.keys(a).map(b=>`${b}=${a[b]}`).join(',');
```

```js
let a = {a: 'apple', b:'ball', c:'cat'}
a = `${Object.keys(a).map(b => `${b}=${a[b]}`)}`
console.log(a)
```

```js
let a = {a: 'apple', b:'ball', c:'cat'}
a = ""+Object.keys(a).map(b => `${b}=${a[b]}`)
console.log(a)
```

```js
let a = {a: 'apple', b:'ball', c:'cat'}
a=""+Object.entries(a).map(x=>x.join('='))
console.log(a)
```

According to VLAZ we cannot get it shorter than

```js
let a=""+Object.entries({a:'apple',b:'ball',c:'cat'}).map(x=>x.join('='))
console.log(a)
```

Comment: `+""` is 3 characters, `\`${}\`` is 5 :P

Comment: I already commented that toString was shorter than join(",") but changed my mind

Comment: My point is that `+""` will still convert to a string and it's shorter than using a template literal.

Comment: I know. I tried the literal before I tested the toString

Comment: I can't really think of anything that can make it shorter. Except perhaps dropping the second assignment to `a` and putting the object: `let a=""+Object.entries({a:'apple',b:'ball',c:'cat'}).map(x=>x.join('='));` saves up the two characters `a=`.

Comment: and the newline and/or semicolon ;)

Comment: For therecord, another take is `(""+new URLSearchParams(a)).replace(/&/g,",")` but it's only 2 characters less than OP's original one. Even removing the `','` beats it. But it's fun, at least.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Your first answer was easiest way to solve this. however your all methods are better and neat.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the entries and map joined key/value pairs.

```js
let object = { a: 'apple', b: 'ball', c: 'cat' },
    result = Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(a => a.join('='))
        .join(',');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is much better and neat code than my code.