# Is there a one-liner to concatenate the key and values of a dict of unknown size into a string in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dictionary

I am trying to parse a dictionary into a string in one line as elegantly as possible.

The string could have anywhere from 1 key value pair to 10.

The dictionary I have:

```js
var dict = {
  rel: 'preload', 
  as: 'image', 
  type: 'image/webp'
}
```

And I am trying to parse it into a query string converting it into:

```js
return "rel='preload' as='image' type='image/webp'"
```

I know that using Object.keys and forEach i can traverse the Dict but how do i concatinate it as well in the same statement?

This is how far i have gotten:

```js
Object.keys(dict).forEach(key => console.log(`${key}="${dict(key)}"`) )
```

How do i concatinate the result of that in the same line? Is it possible?
I have been trying with:

```js
.reduce()
.push()
.concat()
.join()
```

but can't seem to get it to work in one line.

Comment: Why does it have to be in one line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to join Object key value pair with =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215522/simplest-way-to-join-object-key-value-pair-with)

Comment: Thanks, @gre_gor, tho the answer is the same the question itself is different and I looked pretty hard and could not find a direct answer to the question.

Comment: Also, non of the answers were clear just code dumps. @jsN00b actually answered the question and didn't just dump code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to obtain the desired result.

```js
const dict = {
  rel: 'preload', 
  as: 'image', 
  type: 'image/webp'
};
console.log(
  Object.entries(dict)
  .map(([k, v]) => (`${k}='${v}'`))
  .join(' ')
);
```

It uses

- Object.entries() - to obtain key-value pairs from object
- .map() - to iterate over key-value pairs
- backtick ` - to transform each pair to desired structure
- .join() - to finally transform the array into a string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`:

```js
const dict = {
  rel: 'preload', 
  as: 'image', 
  type: 'image/webp'
};

let result = Object.keys(dict).reduce((acc, key) => acc + `${key}=${dict[key]} ` ,'');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

This line may work for you:

```js
const dict = {
  rel: 'preload', 
  as: 'image', 
  type: 'image/webp'
};

const result = Object.entries(dict).map(item => `${item[0]} = '${item[1]}'`).join(' ')

console.log(result)
```